# pycharm tries to commit embedded repositories within a gitignored folder

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

I have a particular folder added into .gitignore file, thus I do not want any version controlling on it. Within that folder, there are a few subfolders that I added exception in the gitignore file so that I would only track changes on those subdirectories of the ignored folder. It was working ok so far.

However, I recently cloned another public repo in the ignored folder (other than the exempted subfolders) that I only need to use locally. Now, whenever I want to commit the project through pycharm's vcs, I get a part of this cloned repository's files and folders in tracked changes list to be commited.

At first try, terminal `git add .` also warned me that I am trying to add embedded repository and I should have used git submodules instead. Then I `git rm -rf -cached ./my_ignored_folder` and got rid of this issue. Now I can use the terminal git, but can't manage the Pycharm git.

Theoretical question, isn't git supposed to ignore anything under a gitignored folder?
Practical question is: how can I make pycharm completely ignore this situation while I keep tracking the exception subdirectories within this ignored folder.

Comment: Is that cloned repository listed in `File - Settings - Version Control`?

Comment: hi @user2235698, yes they are listed in directories there. I unlisted them there and it worked! I can set yours as correct answer if you could write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing cloned repository from `File - Settings - Version Control`